# Is it ever possible to suspend the PM from the House of Commons?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, house-of-commons, procedure, prime-minister

From this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_from_the_UK_parliament) page, it states that

> Members of Parliament (MPs) can be suspended from sitting in the House of Commons by the Speaker for "disorderly conduct". The Speaker can order that an MP is removed from the house until the end of the day.

Would this apply to a prime minister (in the United Kingdom)? If not, what would be the alternative consequences?

Of course, this is just hypothetical as it is extremely unlikely that this would occur.

Comment: It happened in [New Zealand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH0pgu2SojY). Unfortunately, RT is terrible at editing, but I can't find a better video.

Comment: I don't see why they would carve out a special exception for the PM in this regard. As was covered here in another question, the very position of the PM is not well codified.

Comment: In Australia "No prime minister has been sanctioned for disorderly behaviour but two deputy prime ministers and seven opposition leaders have, although not all have been ordered from the House." The implication is clearly that in theory the PM could also be sanctioned that. https://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1314/DisorderlyConduct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the PM is a member of parliament, and subject to the same requirements of orderly conduct as any other MP.

If the speaker "names" the Prime Minister, he must leave the chamber. The only MP exempt from this rule is the speaker (or the deputy speaker when acting as speaker)